# How to insert a div with unique ID for each table

Tags: jquery

I work on a website where there are many tables on each pages. I want to add a scroll bar at the top. I search and found this: http://jsfiddle.net/simo/67xSL/
Now, I try to adapt it so that each table gets it's own scroll bar.
This is what I have done so far:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function(index) {
var base ='thescroll wpt'
var thediv ='thedivfix thediv'
var counter=0;
var theclass= base+counter;
var theinnerdiv = thediv+counter;
jQuery('table.tablepress').each(function(){
    jQuery( "table.tablepress" ).before('<div class="'+theclass+'"><div class="'+theinnerdiv+'"></div></div>');
    jQuery(theclass).on('scroll', function (e) {
        jQuery(theinnerdiv).scrollLeft(jQuery(theclass).scrollLeft());
    }); 
    jQuery(theinnerdiv).on('scroll', function (e) {
        jQuery(theclass).scrollLeft(jQuery(theinnerdiv).scrollLeft());
    });
    jQuery(window).on('load', function (e) {
        jQuery(theinnerdiv).width(jQuery('table.tablepress').width());
    });
})
```

});

Actually, the counter stays at 0 and many scroll bar appear instead of only one for each table. How could I fix that?

Comment: you need to increment counter inside of your jquery.each loop... (counter++;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code the counter is outside the `each` block thats why it is always 0. Move it inside the each block and increment it after each iteration it will generate new id/class everytime.

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function(index) {
var base ='thescroll wpt'
var thediv ='thedivfix thediv'
var counter=0;

jQuery("table.tablepress").each(function(){
    var theclass= base+counter;
    var theinnerdiv = thediv+counter;
    jQuery(this).before('<div class="'+theclass+'"><div class="'+theinnerdiv+'"></div></div>');
    jQuery(theclass).on('scroll', function (e) {
        jQuery(theinnerdiv).scrollLeft(jQuery(theclass).scrollLeft());
    }); 
    jQuery(theinnerdiv).on('scroll', function (e) {
        jQuery(theclass).scrollLeft(jQuery(theinnerdiv).scrollLeft());
    });
    jQuery(window).on('load', function (e) {
        jQuery(theinnerdiv).width(jQuery('table.tablepress').width());
    });
    counter++;
})
```

Comment: Great! It works. Only thing: 5 div are generated before each table if my page contains 5 tables.

Comment: There was a bug in your code which I fixed. Try it now.

Comment: Thank you @ShankarSangoli. Now it works perfect. (I noticed the jQuery(this) ;) )

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the jQuery method `$.now()` to generate a long number representing the current time in milliseconds. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.now/

If you want to make sure that the number is not used twice you can save it into an array and look if the entry exists from earlier - if it does, then generate a new one.

You can also use the number generated and randomize it with the `Math.random()` method

Or simply increment the variable `counter` that you have defined by adding `counter++` at the end of your `each` and then create yours id's the following way `id="myid_'+ counter"`